# Can We Use nearby place search api to get Locations like "Filling Stations " etc..?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here IS My Code example which works fine for "Schools,Restaurants" but not working for Filling stations..I think the space is the problem..

```
case R.id.B_restaurant:
            mMap.clear();
            dataTransfer = new Object[2];
            String restaurant = "restaurant";
            url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, restaurant);
            getNearbyPlacesData = new com.example.husnainbutt.driveescuev22.**GetNearbyPlacesData();**
            dataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            dataTransfer[1] = url;

            getNearbyPlacesData.execute(dataTransfer);
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Showing Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
```

And GetNearbyplaces is following below It seems to look fine but i can't figure out the problem with keyword which includes space plz help me soi can save my time ..!!

```
public class GetNearbyPlacesData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

String googlePlacesData;
GoogleMap mMap;
String url;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... objects) {
    mMap = (GoogleMap)objects[0];
    url = (String)objects[1];

    com.example.husnainbutt.driveescuev22.DownloadURL downloadUrl = new com.example.husnainbutt.driveescuev22.DownloadURL();
    try {
        googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return googlePlacesData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList = null;
    com.example.husnainbutt.driveescuev22.DataParser parser = new com.example.husnainbutt.driveescuev22.DataParser();
    nearbyPlaceList = parser.parse(s);
    showNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlaceList);
}

private void showNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String,String>> nearbyPlaceList)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<nearbyPlaceList.size() ; i++)
    {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String , String> googlePlace = nearbyPlaceList.get(i);
        Log.d("onPostExecute","Entered into showing locations");

        String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
        String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
        double lat = Double.parseDouble( googlePlace.get("lat") );
        double lng = Double.parseDouble( googlePlace.get("lng"));

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(placeName +" : "+ vicinity);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Place`-Types:
https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=de

Using the type "gas_station" should help.

Comment: Thank you..! It seems to look Time saver..coz filling stations aren't available.